# Passing a Variable to Subfolder

Tags: batch-file, command-line, command

I'm a bit stuck here.
Running a batch file that has a couple of steps.
I need to run a batch file in a folder go through each folder and 3 folders down assign that a variable. So copy that 3rd folder down in each folder
So my folder structure

e.g1: 2135698563325\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\c007

eg2: 21356486543248\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\c111

```
REM get c007 as a variable to be able to set a folder name
set variable = Folder0\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\%Variable%

REM Step 2:Check that the c007 folder doens't already exist
if %Variable%==\\hippo\Folder4\ ((echo "Error: Duplicate Folder"):eof) Else mkdir \\hippo\Folder4\%Variable%

REM Step 3:Copy a default File Structure from Template Dir
xCopy /s \\hippo\production\Folder4\Temaplate \\hippo\production\Folder4\%Variable%
Rem Step 4: Copy the contents of c007 in to Folder6
xCopy /s %Variable% \\hippo\production\Folder4\Variable\Folder5\Folder6\
```

Does this make more sense?

Comment: should be `%variable%` instead of `variable` in all your code.

Comment: Okay so i can change that but still not sure how to go through each folder and assing that 3rd folder down a variable?

Comment: Can you edit your post with an example of what you get and what you would need instead? I'm a bit lost here. for instance the 2nd line of your script cannot really work as is.

Comment: Hey Jean, I can't start the script cause i'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I need my script to get the name of a subfolder, from with in that root folder. Eg: 2135698563325\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\c007 where c007 will change then on \\hippo\production\Folder4\c007 then create that folder if it doesn't exist but create a folder structure from a template dir

Comment: Please put any clarification and extra information into your question by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38481632/edit) it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a comment batch script on how to get `c007` and `c111`. Put your code into the subroutine `ProcessFolder`. The folder names `c007` and `c111` are passed to the subroutine via first argument referenced with `%~1`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions

rem Get current directory path always without backslash at end. Environment
rem variable CD holds the current directory path usually without backslash
rem at end. But current directory string is with backslash at end if the
rem current directory is the root directory of a drive.
if "%CD:~-1%" == "\" (
    set "CurrentFolder=%CD:~0,-1%"
) else (
    set "CurrentFolder=%CD%"
)

rem Process the folder names 4 levels below current directory.
for /D %%A in ("%CurrentFolder%\*") do (
    for /D %%B in ("%%A\*") do (
        for /D %%C in ("%%B\*") do (
            for /D %%D in ("%%C\*") do (
                for /D %%E in ("%%D\*") do (
                    call :ProcessFolder "%%~nxE"
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

endlocal
rem Avoid a fall through to the subroutine by exiting batch processing here.
goto :EOF

rem Subroutine to process the folder with name found above.

:ProcessFolder
echo Folder variable is: %~1

rem Exit subroutine and continue in the most inner FOR loop above.
goto :EOF
```

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`